# Trying to install apache, but it says "package apache2 is not available"

Tags: software-installation, apache2, php7

```
sudo apt install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Have you tried to `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` before installing `apache2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most installation manuals recommends the good practice to update the repository and upgrade the existing packages before install a new one. So try:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade 
sudo apt install apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Tasksel**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tasksel) is a Debian/Ubuntu tool that installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated "task" onto your system.

**Installation:**

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

**Usage:**

```
sudo tasksel
```

The tasksel menu will be shown, select the *checkbox* you need
 type <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
 wait… done.

**Installation from `terminal lamp-server`** (Apache/PHP/MySQL Server)

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

**Optional for PHP:**

```
sudo apt-get install php php-mysql php-mbstring php-all-dev php-cgi libapache2-mod-php php-imagick
```

**PhpMyAdmin**

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```